# Making websites as small as possible

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions, bandwidth

So I am about to be in a position where I have an extremely limited amount of data use for the next 2 weeks.

I am just wondering if there is an application out there(native or addon for a browser, etc.) that makes websites smaller in terms of bandwidth usage. I'm assuming something that blocks flash scripts would cut out a lot of clutter but is there anything that can go a step further than that and maybe block all the javascript?   I only plan to be studying for the next couple of weeks so i assume that I will only need to view text on webpages.

Comment: Your question may be on topic at Software Recommendations if you can rewrite it so that it meets their [quality guidelines](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question appears to be looking for a short term work around rather then a longer term Software Recommendation there is a web tool that simulates the text based output you would get on the Lynx Browser.  The Lynx browser uses an 80 column text only output and as such would cut your data usage to an absolute bare minimum.  This tool can be found at http://www.delorie.com/web/lynxview.html and is 100% free of any registration or charge.

Note that this tool can be a bit slow to process a request depending on the size of the target site in question. I have no affiliation with this site.